# Errors attempting to use Google maps directions in Magento (Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, magento, google-maps-api-3

I've created a directions template file specifically to utilize Google directions. I have the script working outside Magento. Unfortunately when I move the script into page/directions.phtml console returns the following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

when I try clicking on test which fires off the calcRoute() function, I get the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'route' of undefined"

I'm thinking these errors have something to do with the Google Maps API call, however The graphical map is displaying and functioning just fine on the page. These errors relate specifically to the google.maps.DirectionsService() being called to define directionsService on line 2 of the javascript shown below and directionsService.route being called towards the end. Both relate to directions.

Why would the map display, but the directions throw errors when the script works as is inside my html test? I'm so confused.

**Javascript**

```
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function directionsMap() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(38.77627, -95.910965);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom:4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-directions'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    //Place Markers
    var baldwinsvilleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(00.00000, 00.00000),
        map: map,
        title:"store location 1"
    });
    var sacramentoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(00.00000, 00.00000),
        map: map,
        title:"store location 2"
    });
    var stLouisMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(000.00000, -000.00000),
        map: map,
        title:"store location 3"
    });
    var catersvilleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(00.000000, -84.000000),
        map: map,
        title:"store location 4"
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("get-directions"));

  }

  function calcRoute() {
    console.log("calcRoute ran")
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    console.log(start + ' ' + end)
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
           #I am including this line in the document head
           <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
           <style onload="directionsMap()">
            #map-directions{width: 65%; height: 300px; float: left; border:5px solid #EEEEEE;}
            #get-directions{width: 65%; float: left;}
            .map-sidebar{width: 32%; height: 300px; float: right;}
            </style>

            <div id="map-directions"></div>
            <div class="map-sidebar">
                <h2>Get Directions</h2>

                <input type="text" id="start" value="chicago, il"/>
                <b>End: </b>
                <select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">

                  <option value="value 1">
                      store location 1
                  </option>

                  <option value="value 2">
                      store location 2
                  </option>

                  <option value="value 3">
                      store location 3
                  </option>

                  <option value="value 4">
                      store location 4
                  </option>

                </select>
                <button onclick="calcRoute();"> test</button>


            </div>
            <div id="get-directions"></div>
```

Comment: Are you calling the javascript you posted before the google api? I cannot see from your code where you are calling it.

Comment: This was the problem, see the comments under the answer I chose. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow a step by step call like:

1. first call the google map api
2. then call your own JS
3. fire `directionsMap()` in `body onload=directionsMap()`, not `style` onload.

I think your main issue is, you're calling `directionsMap()` function before google complete its loading.

So I think its better option to call `directionsMap()` within jQuery load event like:

```
$(function() {
   directionsMap()
});
```

Comment: Sorry I had it in style while I was troubleshooting something. It is on my body tag. What you're suggesting is exactly what I'm doing. If I swap steps one and two you listed the map simply doesn't load. The fact that the map is loading leads me to believe that it is being called.

Comment: You're correct!!! I put some breakpoints in to test this specifically.  It must be partially loaded hence why the map is displaying but something about the order is messing it up. I tested the theory by moving my JS into the document (only to guarantee it was after the call). On paper it looks like the load order is correct, in reality it's not. Thanks for your help.